# How to set index of row in Angular column with grouped data

Tags: angular

I have problem with setting index in Angular table. Situation is that I have some parameter to group data in table, each group have header and I don't have fixed number of rows in each group. So I need global index in td tag but I have array of arrays (ng container around tr tag) and classic index of row is not option (I got in each new group index from 0). Any suggestion to achieve this only in html?